# How to enable Design View (GUI) for xml files other than the layout xml in Android Studio?

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, android-studio

In Eclipse using ADT, 
  It's possible to add xml tags for all the resources, whether it be AndroidManifest , values..
I don't see a Design View (GUI interface) for the same in Android Studio.

Any way to enable it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open a xml layout or drawable.
Go to the bottom left of the android studio window, you should see a TV like icon, hover over it, and select Preview,

Now a preview pane will be opened(generally, at right side of the window) which shows the design.